# Sending Keystroke

Tags: c#, windows, sendkeys

Im using `SendKey` and those functions to send keystrokes to a window located by its Window Name

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int FindWindow(
    string lpClassName, // class name 
    string lpWindowName // window name 
    );

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SetForegroundWindow(
    int hWnd // handle to window
    );
```

Is there another way to send keystroke to a window without putting it in the foreground ?

Im switching between many windows and `SendKey` is making some errors that I can't control, I can't use `SendWait` no either putting some thread delays, it has to be the fastest possible ,

Im just looking how it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think Windows Architecture will allow that, because only forground window is supposed to receive keystrokes or any user acitivity.

Alternate way could be creating virtual destkop, moving your desktop in that virtual desktop and passing keys which could not be visible on screen.